# "Ignoring" files with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to ignore all actual files in a directory with `RewriteRules`? What I mean is, I'm creating "flatlinks" or "permalinks" (http://example.com/not/an/actual/file/path/) that page.php handles. This only works if I 'ignore' all other files with `RewriteCond`. Instead of creating a `RewriteCond` for every real file in the directory in my .htaccess file is there a way to tell it to check if there is an actual file show that and if not let page.php take care of it?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/somefile\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/someotherfile\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page\.php$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /page.php?p=$1 [L] [NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following indicates that the redirect should be executed only when the requested file (`-f`) or folder (`-d`) does not exist (`!`) on disk:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /page.php?p=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Works a treat! You were first so you get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is very much possible. Add these lines before your existing code:

```
## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```